# Java nio FileSystem change root path

Tags: java, path, nio

I need to know if there is a way to change the root path of a FileSystem.

I instantiate it like this:

```
import java.nio.file.FileSystem;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
```

---

```
final Path path = Paths.get(workingFilePath);
final URI uri = URI.create("jar:" + path.toUri());

Filesystem fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri, env);
```

I did not find any method to do it.

Greetings, Andy

Comment: What do you mean? Renaming the zip must be done without `jar:`; any directory in the zip can use Files.rename/move too.

Comment: Changing the root of a filesystem is an OS level operation.  On Linux it would be necessary to unmount it, reconfigure its root in fstab and then remount it. Instructions for doing it on windows are at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753321.aspx. This could be run by running an external script from a Java app provided the filesystem is not in use but it may be possible for force the initial dismount.